# Admin Panel Style is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Admin Panel all functionalities are working but the style is not working.

[image: Admin Panel]

The console shows the following errors:

```
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/custom.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/sm/cameraslide/css/cameraslide.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/sm/cameraslide/css/font-awesome.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/base/default/aw_blog/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/sm/cameraslide/css/cameraslide.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/base/default/aw_blog/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/sm/cameraslide/css/font-awesome.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/custom.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your skin folder does not have proper permission.

give `755` permission to folder and `644` to files in skin folder.

here are below commnad for permission

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

**Edit**

As per your comment you miss the boxes.css file, please download magento default package and upload `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css` file in this path, this will solve your Problem

Comment: Does this apply for the sub folders and files too?

Comment: Yes this apply to subfolder to.

Comment: The above commands did not solve the problem.

Comment: check your browser console for error

Comment: public_html/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @AhmadReshadZazai Download Magento default package and upload this css file to your server , this css file is missing in your server , hope  this will solve your problem, if this will solve your problem then mark this answer as accepted

Comment: I have check the above files are actually there but I dont know why it gives error 404, do you recommend me with the replacing those files with the one from the default package.

Comment: @AhmadReshadZazai yes May be some issue with this file replace and flush magento cache storage and try again

Comment: Replacing the mentioned files fixed the problem but  just I refresh the admin panel or if I navigate to flush the cache the problem is back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed after changing the Merge JavaScript Files and Merge CSS Files to No in admin panel.